# Vb.net: Word Table to Excel Data Transfer Issue

Tags: excel, vb.net, ms-word, cell

I can successfully transfer the data... My only question is what are these strange rectangles being put in every entry in the Excel sheet?

[image]

I plan using information based in this sheet to query from and am wondering what they are, why it happened, and how to get rid of them.

Comment: A tab, carriage return, line feed, or something else? Did the data originate by any change in a different operating system? Also, put some code in your question showing how you transfer the data.

Comment: Probably carriage return, line feed and/or tab characters. In other words "unprintable" characters.

Comment: How would I go about removing these "unprintable characters" @topshot

Comment: Do you already do `String.Trim()` on all the entries? It would be easier to help if you provide some code.

Comment: Use [String.Trim()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove all leading and trailing [white space characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: so the value I was originally putting in the excel cells was `keyText`. I then did `cleanStringKey = keyText.Trim` and I was having the same issue, Good suggestion though, I thought it would work! @Verdolino

Comment: Once you know which one(s) it is, you can `Replace` it with an empty string. `str = str.Replace(Chr(13), "")` to get rid of carriage return, for example.

Comment: Check the last character. `Dim index = AscW(cleanStringKey.Trim.Last())`. What is the value of `index`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your content is from a word table cell then that is likely the Word "end of cell marker" (ASCII 7)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/165928

> **Symptoms**
>
> When your Visual Basic for Applications macro returns the
>   number of characters within a range of a table cell, if that range
>   includes the entire cell, the number of characters returned is one
>   more than expected.
>
> **Cause**
>
> By design, the End of Cell Mark (ASCII
>   character number 7) is returned as part of the text when the cell
>   range is set to include the entire cell. Using the Range.Text property
>   includes the paragraph mark and the end of cell mark (ASCII 13 and
>   ASCII 7) and returns them as a pair.